# Crystal Report based on table created with "Create Table"

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a table using the T SQL Create Table. I do not know how (or if you can add) it to the dataset.

is it possible to use such a table with CR? I have completed a desktop application that uses a SQL Server CE database. I want to add new tables to the existing dB without having to retype the information because I distributed a new dB with the update.

I have the following code:

```
    Dim con As New SqlCeConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\VS 2012\Projects\Create Fields\Create Fields\TestDatabase.sdf"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Create table tblTabTest2 (ID bigint Identity, Companies bigint);"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

This adds the table to the database, but how do I use tblTabTest2 in a Crystal Report?

Thanks,

Ralph

Thanks

Comment: what is your exact requirement? Add new tables to exsting database or add tables to crystal reports?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add a table in CR. If your CR is existing then set new Table in Database Location option on CR..

Comment: I want to add tables to the existing database, Siva.

Comment: What I meant to say is:  I want to add tables to the existing database, so that I can build reports off of the new tables.